# Java URLDecoder special characters and UTF-8

Tags: java, url, utf-8, uri

Take the string Mediæval%20Bæbes. It can be encoded in the URL as either Medi%E6val+B%E6bes Mediæval%20Bæbes. On the first I get the correct æ character when decoded. The latter gives me � (the replacement character). I can't figure out how to get Java to decode it both ways, possibly in the same URL. I tried java.net.URI and apache's URLCodec as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never find a solution to this puzzle because these two strings are in two different encodings. UTF-8 for `æ` is %C3%A6, %E6 is ISO-8859-1. It can only work like this

```
String s1 = URLDecoder.decode("Medi%E6val+B%E6bes", "ISO-8859-1");
String s2 = URLDecoder.decode("Mediæval%20Bæbes", "UTF-8");
String s3 = URLDecoder.decode("Medi%C3%A6val%20B%C3%A6bes", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is the safe encoding: the second is not, and therefore does not work.

See [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm)

Edit: better reference